# Elementor Form data: Changing Field content before submission

Tags: forms, elementor

There are several good examples of validating Elementor field data and returning error messages.

But how does one **replace field data before form submission**? Example: Properly capitalize name fields?   With Gravity Forms this is done simply with `add_filter`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear Bot.  How do you suggest I provide a code example for code I can not write - hence the question asked ?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/process', 'process_test_data', 10, 2);

function  process_test_data($record, $handler) {
    
    // filter FORM name
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    if ( 'test' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );

    // assign fields to local variable
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[$id] = $field['value'];
    }
    
    // do what you want with the field data
    $capitalize = ucwords( $fields['name'], ' ' );
    
    // update raw_field values
    $raw_fields['name']['value'] = $capitalize;
    $raw_fields['name']['raw_value'] = $capitalize;
    
    // save record
    $record->set( 'fields', $raw_fields );
    
}
```

The hook elementor_pro/forms/process will be triggered after form validation which enables you to modify the submitted values before saving in the submissions CPT.

reference: https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/forms/#form-processing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).